# Proving a (simple) step for the Skorokhod representation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am working on a slight variation of the proof of the Skorokhod representation theorem, as found in [Bogachev, Vol. II](https://www.abebooks.com/9783540345138/Measure-Theory-2-Volume-Set-3540345132/plp). In particular, I want to use another definition of the functions $F_\mu,\xi_\mu$.

Let $X=[0,1]$, $\mu$ a probability measure on $(X,\mathscr{B}(X))$; define $F_\mu(x):=\mu([0,x])$ and
$$\xi_\mu(t)=\inf\{x \in [0,1]:F_\mu(x)\geq t\}$$
Let the sequence of probability measures $\mu_n\to \mu$ weakly. I would want to prove $\xi_{\mu_n}\to \xi_\mu$, $\lambda$-a.e. where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. I start with the following facts:

- $\xi_\mu(t)\leq x\iff F_\mu(x)\geq t$
  , which implies $\xi_\mu(t)> x\iff F_\mu(x)< t$;
- $\xi_\mu$ is left-continuous nondecreasing: the set of discontinuity points is countable.
- $F_{\mu_n}(x)\to F_\mu(x)$ at all continuity points of $F_\mu$; again the set of discontinuity points is countable.

---

**Now I proceed: what could be the issues with this argument?**

Suppose
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}\xi_{\mu_n}(t)<\xi_\mu(t)-2\varepsilon$$
We choose $x_0\in (\xi_\mu(t)-2\varepsilon,\xi_\mu(t)-\varepsilon)$ a continuity point of $F_\mu$. Then, for a subsequence, $\xi_{\mu_{n_k}}(t)<x_0,\,\forall k$. Then $t\leq F_{\mu_{n_k}}(x_0)\to F_\mu(x_0)\implies \xi_\mu(t)\leq x_0$, contradiction. So $\liminf_{n \to \infty}\xi_{\mu_n}(t)\geq \xi_\mu(t)$. Suppose that for some $\eta >0$
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\xi_{\mu_n}(t)>\xi_\mu(t+\eta)+2\varepsilon$$
We choose $x_0\in (\xi_\mu(t+\eta)+\varepsilon,\xi_\mu(t+\eta)+2\varepsilon)$ a continuity point of $F_\mu$. Then, for a subsequence, $\xi_{\mu_{n_k}}(t)>x_0,\,\forall k$. We get
$$\begin{aligned}\xi_{n_k}(t)>x_0&\implies F_{\mu_{n_k}}(x_0)<t\implies \\
&\implies F_\mu(x_0)\leq t<t+\eta\implies \\
&\implies \xi_{\mu}(t+\eta)> x_0\end{aligned}$$
a contradiction. We obtain
$$\xi_\mu(t)\leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}\xi_{\mu_n}(t)\leq \limsup_{n \to \infty}\xi_{\mu_n}(t)\leq\xi_\mu(t^+) $$
So if $t$ is a continuity point of $\xi_\mu$, we have $\xi_{\mu_n}(t)\to \xi_\mu(t)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence in probability implies convergence in quantile of inverse quantile.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260647/convergence-in-probability-implies-convergence-in-quantile-of-inverse-quantile). This [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260816/121671) has an argument like the one you have in your posting (without calling the result by name)

Comment: @OliverDíaz hello, yes, I think your answer there answers the question (+1); but could you have a quick look on my attempt? It is similar

Comment: I did go through your posting. It seems fine. That triggered my memory.

Comment: furthermore, this (the result in your posting, that is) would also imply the Skorokhod representation theorem in Polish spaces provided that (which required herculean work) it has been established that any Polish space is measurable isomorphic to a Borel set in $(0,1)$, but I am sure you know all this stuff.